# Problema al iniciar el servidor de rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Acabo de crear un proyecto en rails, modifique el Gemfile para añadir gem 'javascript', '~> 0.1.0' y lugo use bundle install para instalar las gemas y me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version que utilizo de rails es la 7.0.2.3 y la gema de bootsnap es gem "bootsnap", require: false.

En el boot.rb añadi la siguiente linea

`unless (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)`

despues de

`require "bootsnap/setup"`

y ahora el mensaje es otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que eres un usuario antiguo deberías saberlo, pero por favor agrega el texto a tu pregunta [en vez de pantallazos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binding_of_caller` es compatible con ruby 3 [desde la versión 1.0](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/releases/tag/v1.0.0), así que actualízalo con:

```
bundle update binding_of_caller
```